# Is $L^2(0,T;H_n)$ compactly embedded in $L^2(0,T;H)$?

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Let $H$ be a separable Hilbert space with basis $h_i.$ Let 
$$H_n := \text{span}\{h_1,...,h_n\}.$$
Questions:

1) Is $L^2(0,T;H_n)$ compactly embedded in $L^2(0,T;H)$?

2) Is $L^2(0,T;H_n^*)$ compactly embedded in $L^2(0,T;H^*)$?

I have no idea how to even begin. Any hints would be appreciated.

Comment: what is your definition of compactly embedded?

Comment: @Norbert It is: $X$ is compactly embedded in $Y$ if every bounded sequence in $X$ has a convergent subsequence in $Y$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No**.

$\mathbb{R}$ is a separable Hilbert space with basis $\{h_1\} = \{1\}$; $L^2(0,T;\mathbb{R})$ clearly does not compactly embed in itself.

For any $\mathbb{R}$-Hilbert space $H$ we have that $H = H \otimes_{\mathbb{R}} \mathbb{R}$ and a bounded sequence $f_k$ in $L^2(0,T;\mathbb{R})$ with no converging subsequences gives a counterexample in $L^2(0,T;H)$ if you consider the elements $h_1 \otimes f_k$.

Comment: If you want an explicit example, consider $\tilde{f}_n(t) = \sin(2\pi n t/ T) h_1$.